# Finding Number of pages from the total number of digits used to number the pages

Tags: c, loops

I am stuck in a problem where the user inputs the total number of digits used in numbering the pages and the program gives the total number of pages in the book.

(i.e. a book of 10 pages needs 11 digits to number because the numbers 1-9 are written with one digit and the number 10 is written with two digits; an 11 pages book requires 13 digits ...).

I tried it by using a `while` loop but it does not run as it exceeds the execution time.

My C code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, pages = 9;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 9) {
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        printf("Invalid input");
    }
    else {
        while (n < 9) {
            pages++;
            n -= 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: We need your code to know what has to be done..

Comment: could you please write the main function or tell me the logic to be used

Comment: could you please give the pseudo code for this problem

Comment: I am afraid if you do not give enough details about your problem, the question may be closed. Furthermore, it seems to me that this looks like a homework problem.

Comment: @4386427 The problem is independent of the programming language, I think. So maybe the tags shall be removed...

Comment: I don't think you need a loop to solve this problem. The pages 1 ... 9 need one digit per page, the pages 10 ... 99 two digits per page, etc. This could be solved e.g. by some `if`s and knowing the max. number of supported pages at all.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It this some university task, the professor wants to see a "generic" approach that works for unlimited numbers (assuming the data types used are unlimited).

Comment: @MartinRosenau Even then a max. number would be necessary to care about the resp. integral type to use without being afraid of overflow. This could be a problem in C as well as C++.

Comment: The logic I have used in while loop is wrong as i did not consider books with 3 digit pages

Comment: @MadhurankHegde We could have told you **if you had posted your code**. If you want help here, you need to show us your code. How do you expect we can help when we can't see the code????

Comment: The first 9 pages get one digit per page, the next 90 pages two digits, the next 900 three digits per page, etc. There is pattern which can be implemented in a loop with some sums and products.

Comment: @MadhurankHegde "... i did not consider books with 3 digit pages" And 4 digit, 5 digit, 6 digit pages... did you remember those?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat This is why I wrote "assuming the data types are unlimited": The data type `unsigned int` is 16 bits on MS-DOS and 32 bits on Linux and maybe it is 128 bits on some other system. If I was an university professor, I would want to see a program that works with page numbers up to 2^32 on Linux and up to 2^128 on the other system...

Comment: How is this impemented in code. I am not able to understand this logic thats where i am stuck

Comment: I will update the question with my trial

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,pages=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<=9)
    {
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    else if(n%2==0)
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
    }
    else
    {
        while(n!=0)
        {
            pages++;
            n-=2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Do the task description include a maximum for the number of pages?

Comment: between 1 and 2 billion

Comment: @Madhurank Hegde "I am not able to understand this logic thats where i am stuck" - the trick is to **do it in reverse**. Imagine you have N pages (say, 15). How many digits you need *relating to N*? Try with growing values of N. You will see a relation: a given number of pages gives you a distinctive amount of digits D. Once you have this observation, and the relation between N and D, implement it in reverse.

Comment: @MadhurankHegde 1~2 billion of the page means that you must not use the looping to solve the problem. Actually there is a formula for calculating it.

Comment: How do I arrive at the formula.

Comment: @4386427  yes i can use 64 bit

Comment: And what do you want to do with illegal input like e.g. 12 ?

Comment: @4386427 tell/printf that the input is invalid

Comment: @MadhurankHegde: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> else if(n%2==0)
> {
>     printf("Invalid input");
> }
> ```

Please note that there are books with more than 100 pages:

A book with 102 pages has 198 digits!

> ```
>  while(n!=0)
>  {
>      pages++;
>      n-=2;
>  }
> ```

This loop will run forever:

Because `n` is initially an odd number, `n-2` is also odd. So `n` will always be odd (maybe negative) if `n-=2` is the only instruction that modifies `n`. `n` cannot become 0, so the loop will run forever.

You also have to consider that books with more than 100 pages or with more than 1000 pages may exist.

I would do it the other way round and count `pages` up from 1 to N. I would sum up the digits required for the given number of pages and stop when the number of digits is exceeded:

```
int n, pages=0, digits=0;
int realdigits=0, neededdigits, tooLarge;

/* "realdigits" is the number of digits required
 * by "pages" pages; loop until
 * "realdigits" >= "digits" */
while(realdigits < digits)
{
    pages++;
    /*
     * Add some code that calculates:
     * neededdigits = Number of digits required by
     *                the number "pages"
     */
    realdigits += neededdigits;
}
/* Case: "(pages-1)" pages need less digits
 * than "digits" but "pages" pages need more
 * digits... */
if(realdigits > digits)
{
    printf("Invalid number\n");
}
else
{
    printf("%d pages\n", pages);
}
```

I would use a loop based on a condition to calculate the number of digits required by the number `pages`:

```
neededdigits = 1;
tooLarge = 10; /* Number that is too large for digits */
while(pages >= tooLarge)
{
    neededdigits++;
    tooLarge *= 10;
}
```

Note that in "C-like" programming languages (C, C++, Java, C#, PHP ...) you may use the `for` keyword for "condition-based" loops ...

Comment: the program takes number of digits as input and gives pages as output.

Comment: @MadhurankHegde I see. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using successive tests like this:

- if the `number <= 9`, the number of pages is `number`, else set `pages = 9` and subtract `9` from `number`.
- if the `number <= 90 * 2`, the number of pages is `pages + number / 2`, else set `pages += 90` and subtract `90 * 2` from `number`.
- if the `number <= 900 * 3`, the number of pages is `pages + number / 3`, else set `pages += 900` and subtract `900 * 3` from `number`.
- etc.

You can write a loop to solve the problem without making an assumption on the range of the type used to store `number` and `pages`.

```
int number_of_pages(int number_of_digits) {
    int n1 = 9, n2 = 1, pages = 0;
    while (number / n2 > n1) {
        pages += n1;
        number -= n1 * n2;
        n1 *= 10;
        n2 += 1;
    }
    return pages + number / n2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No loops! Uses `log10()` and `pow()` from math library.

Based on formula found on [OEIS A058183: "Number of digits in concatenation of first n positive integers."](https://oeis.org/A058183)

```
#include <math.h>

int digits_for_pages(unsigned n) {
    // oeis A058183
    return (n+1)*floor(log10(10*n)) - (pow(10, floor(log10(10*n)))-1)/(10-1);
}
```

<sup>*https://ideone.com/7GJYXq*</sup>

Comment: `pow()` introduces floating-point into the "system" and it's not needed.

Comment: Sold! LOL Thanks. ideone edited too

Comment: Slightly simpler: `return (n + 1) * (1 + floor(log10(n))) - pow(10, floor(log10(n))) / (10 - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

In your posts body you do not ask a question (apart from "Can somebody help me?", which is not considered a question here). In your comments you ask for the `main()` function, or the logic, or the pseudo code. Sorry, that is not how StackOverflow is meant to be used.
But finally you ask how to arrive at the needed formula.
With [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in mind I will help you with that.

- make a table of the simplest case (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) pages and digits, the same
- find the formula for that
- check the next complex case (10,11,12,13,14,...99) pages and digits, there is a very simple relation
- consider which influence the pages 1...9 have on the formula, think offset
- consider the next complex case (100, 101, .... 999)
- and proceed to the mentioned limit of 2 billion pages

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for not following the procedure as I have joined stckoverflow today and i shall not repeat the same

Comment: @MadhurankHegde Although this answer does not show the code or pseudocode, this clearly shows the essential logic you have to follow. I suggest you to mark this as an answer.

Comment: @K.R.Park No need to mark as an answer. It is an answer. Actually I think you might have misunderstood something if you think that answers can be marked as such.... But thanks for what is clearly meant as support. ;-)